# Convert json-like(not JSON) string to an object in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a string like:

```
{InstanceStatuses: [{AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b,Events: [],InstanceId: i-79e234fd, InstanceState: {Code: 16,Name: running},InstanceStatus: {Details: [{Name: reachability,Status: initializing}],Status: initializing},SystemStatus: {Details: [{Name: reachability,Status: initializing}],Status: initializing}}],}
```

how to convert it to an Object(like hashmap) in java? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Where do you get those strings? Because if it is from amazon (I see an amazon tag in your question) it is very likely that an (official) parser already exists for java.
If not, I think your only chance is to write a parser by your own (could get quite difficult).
I think your best choice for the start is to look where you get the string and then search for a java parser.

Comment: @Catchy - please upvote and "accept" this answer - it's basically the *ONLY* answer: 1) If you're getting this string from some vendor (e.g. Amazon), perhaps that vendor has a library.  2) Otherwise, you'll have to parse it yourself.  Looking at the format, I think writing the "parsing code" in Java might actually be pretty easy ;)

Comment: I am not good at string parsing. Can you write a demo? Thank you